# SharePoint 2013 - How to add basic header to a Oslo masterpage?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, master-page

I'd like to add a header to the Oslo masterpage, but I can't figure out how. Does anyone know?

Thank you very much.

This is what I use for the footer of the page.

Update:

```
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderFooter" BlockElement="true" runat="server">
<%--SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="PageFooter"   AllowMultipleControls="false" /--%>
<div id="footer" class="noindex">
<p style="text-align:center;">Some fancy footer is displayed here.</p>
</div>
</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are wanting to do?

Comment: I would just like to add a header at the top of the page. Edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Sergiu,

Bad news, you'll have to edit the master page directly, which means a special master just for that page.  (Line 4, with ContentPlaceHolderId "PlaceHolderPageTitle" is just below "the header" you're looking to edit.)

That said, the best thing I can say is use the Design Manager, build out exactly what you want (Branding-wise) in HTML, then create a master page from said HTML following the instructions.  [How to convert a file, from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822370.aspx)

Yes, there are HTML versions of Oslo that can be used, you'll find them in the Site Collection's Master page Gallery, under ~SiteUrl/_catalogs/masterpage/ .  Alternatively, simply click "Master Pages" under "Web Designer Galleries" in the site settings page of the Site Collection's home web.

There are instructions on adding SharePoint functionality through snippets, which I can replicate when I have more time.

As for where to find this: Go to site settings, then "Design Manager" under "Look and Feel".

Comment: I want this header on all the pages, so I'm fine with editing the master page. What code do I put on PlaceHolderPageFooter in order to activate? I don't want to make it fancy atm, just want to it to come up at the top of the page. That's it.

Comment: You really don't want to do it that way.  Open the Oslo.html file in SPD (or whatever editor of your choosing) and Ctrl-F <div id="titleAreaRow" class="ms-tableRow">.  That's the div that holds the header as current.  Here you'll be able to alter it as needed with pure html. (To include script tags :D) I would state, however, to copy the existing annotated code, SP2013 uses the annotations for precompiler insertion before creating a masterpage.

Comment: To copy the existing annotated code...which code? and copy it where? Thanks.

Comment: Just copy the aforementioned div's inner HTML to notepad, as a backup; I've noticed this stuff's a little... fincky... and it's always good to have a fallback.  Just remember to use the Design Manager to make a master page out of the .html file, and you'll be good.  Also, you can also use the Oslo.preview file as a basis for making a preview file for your new master, should you choose, but it's not mandatory.

Comment: Isn't there any other easy way to do this? The footer works well (the one in my question). Isn't there anyway I could use that or perhaps the AdditionalPageHead? Also, I have a bunch of CSS styles in a script editor at the moment, where can I drop these in order to affect the whole website?

Comment: If it's across the site, it'll have to be the master page, and this method allows you full control of the HTML being presented.  The alternative is finding the same ID in the master, and making your modifications there, but be warned, sharepoint *may* strip your edits at runtime.  Lastly, this is Microsoft's offically supported method as of 2013; and considering the replaced functionality, define 'easier method' ;)

Comment: I'm a newbie, so I just want a basic header for now, without having to create another master etc. Is there an easy way to achieve this? I need more detail explanation. Regarding, the styles, where can I find the oslo.css? it's annoying having to apply them to each page using the script editor? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you want this header to be across every page, you'll have to edit the master eventually, either before it's created or edit the file manually.  Unfortunately, there isn't an "easier" method that I'm aware of, so you'll have to be reliant on another answer, or perhaps we could push this converstation into chat.

Comment: Also, for CSS, try ~SiteUrl/Style Library/

Comment: I'm ok with modifying the masterpage. That's what I did for the header. But I want to know what to modify and where? Thank you.

Comment: In the Style Library, where can I find the oslo.css?

Comment: My apologies, Style Library is a different concept, ~SiteUrl/_catalogs/theme/Themed/ You're better off not trying to replace the original CSS, just declare your own CSS file after the original.  Either way, have fun, be careful.